# How to match for string present after a character if it's present else should not match anything

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume we have following 2 strings:

string - 1: (Full string)

```
char = "port : id 0xa30  State INIT-DOWN (Admin Down | Port Disabled/Link status unknown)  Rate 8100  MeasuredBw 18097"
```

string - 2: (where part of the string is not present. i.e string `'  Rate 8100  MeasuredBw 18097'` is not present)

```
char = "port : id 0xa30  State DOWN (Admin Down, Link Down, ODU Up, CCP Up)"
```

So, I am able to validate the string if part of the string is present or not. But, challenge is when the string is present, I am not able to match the string.

Regex I came up with (not the best though):

```
re.search("port\s+:\s+id\s+(\w+)\s+State\s+(\w+-*\w*)[\(\w\)\|\/\s\,]*(?:Rate\s+(\w+)\s+MeasuredBw\s+(\w+))?", port_state1).groups()
```

Output:

```
('0xa30', 'DOWN', None, None)
```

for both strings.

Expected Output:

```
String-1:  
('0xa30', 'DOWN', '8100', '18097')  
String-2:  
('0xa30', 'DOWN', None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below pattern

**Ex:**

```
import re

char_1 = "port : id 0xa30 State INIT-DOWN (Admin Down | Port Disabled/Link status unknown) Rate 8100 MeasuredBw 18097"
char_2 = "port : id 0xa30 State DOWN (Admin Down, Link Down, ODU Up, CCP Up)"


print(re.search("port\s+:\s+id\s+(\w+)\s+State\s+(\w+-*\w*)\s+\(.*?\)\s*(?:Rate\s+(\d+)\s+MeasuredBw\s+(\d+))?", char_1).groups())
print(re.search("port\s+:\s+id\s+(\w+)\s+State\s+(\w+-*\w*)\s+\(.*?\)\s*(?:Rate\s+(\d+)\s+MeasuredBw\s+(\d+))?", char_2).groups())
```

**Output:**

```
('0xa30', 'INIT-DOWN', '8100', '18097')
('0xa30', 'DOWN', None, None)
```